# Can I prevent loading an entire image on a web page?

Tags: html, css, web-performance

I have a masthead background image on my web page that only about 1/3 of the image is within the bounds to be seen on the page.

Is there any way to load just the slice of the image I need instead of the entire image loading? Google's [page speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/) says my image is the main reason my home page is taking so long to load the first time around.

CSS:

```
header.masthead {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #343a40;
  background: url("../images/showcase.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 8rem;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <header class="masthead">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="text-light" >Lorem</h1>
        </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="{{ url_for('billing.pricing') }}"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-main">Ipsum</button></a>
              </div>

        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can cut out the last 2/3 in Photoshop or any other image-editing software.

Comment: [squoosh.app](https://squoosh.app/) is the best-named option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to load just the slice of the image I need instead of the entire image loading?

Short answer: no.

If you're only displaying 1/3 of your image and that applies to all devices, **cropping the image is probably your best bet**.

If you want to fine-tune further, consider [optimizing your image size](https://www.abetterlemonadestand.com/optimizing-images-for-web/) and using [srcset](https://html.com/attributes/img-srcset/) to offer multiple alternatives to the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what platform you run your site, there might be a way to stream / send just a part of the image file to the browser, but that might result in browsers reading it as invalid / incomplete. 
In other cases, such as css crop or resize, the image is still loaded as whole and Speed Insights see it as such, and will know that it it larger then necessary, or only a part is visible.
What keeps you from cropping the image itself, to keep just the visible part?

Comment: Also, if you want to mak Pagespeed happy, optimize tour image. A very easy way to do it is https://tinyjpg.com. Tried it, does the job.

Comment: Your answer is basically just a comment. Also you can edit your "answer" so don't comment on your own answer unless you are answering someone.

Comment: I wrote that a) any css hacking around an image file, to prevent it from being displayed in full such as cropping or scaling is wrong, in terms of page speed b) there is a way to load only a part of the file is doable, but very wrong c) the only way to solve this is to create an  image to fit the space it covers. So, my answer is, in fact a full-fat answer.

Comment: there is no code and no actual solution. Telling someone there "might be a way" to do something isnt helpful. You then end your "answer" by asking for clarification on the actual question. This is most certainly a comment.